# Distance between points - Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Does anyone know how to get the distance between points in geometry nodes?

[image]

I attach de 3.5 .blend file:

[image]

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

you can use this node setup here:

[image]

as you can see in the spreadsheet: the viewer node shows the distance between point 0 and 1.

Of course you can change the indices to your liking.

By this node setup you get all distances to point at index 0:

[image]

Note: that's why the distance at index 0 is 0.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris! But what I need is get the distance from each point to the rest of the points.

Comment: can u tell us your "end goal" what you want to make with it?

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate the distance between all points, so they don't collide when I move them. Like your last example but between all points.

Comment: @Miguel If I'm understanding your intention right, it's probably a much more complicated question (for the current state of Geometry Nodes) than you might realize. I'd suggest either taking a look at Simulation Nodes (for ex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqHOvP59L0o) or for "plexus" setups like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tj6ZZYO5qPY

Comment: Thanks, Kuboå! I had already checked the "merge-by-distance" Seanterelle solution and I've checked the "power-points" Entagma solution but I think none of them is a good option for what I'm trying to do. The first one doesn't give you the distance between points and the second one involves creating many points and it's a bit confusing for me. Anyways, in case someone wants to help me, what I'm trying to replicate in GN is the "Primordial Particle System": https://nagualdesign.github.io/
Explanation: https://youtu.be/makaJpLvbow